# doctrine db validate shows unexisting diff

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, primary-key

Very strange, after I run

```
`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`
```

And than

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

Doctrine still shows:

> [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
>   [Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

I tried to do it again, tried in powershell and command prompt in windows 10 but he still dump same:

```
ALTER TABLE binary_files CHANGE `key` `key` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE config CHANGE name name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE game_data CHANGE name name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE game_history CHANGE name name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE rfid_key CHANGE key_code key_code VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE wheel_stat CHANGE tstamp tstamp DATE NOT NULL;
```

This fields are PRIMARY keys.
What could be wrong? 
I also checked in database update is MADE but doctrine does not see it? 
I also try to clear cache with:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup
```

But nothing happened. Help?

**EDIT**

Ok, I got something. When I remove

```
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
```

from

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="key", type="string", length=64)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $key;
```

everything works fine. I read this

[doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-generatedvalue)

But I still do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I use :

- **Symfony**=3.4.9 (flex)

  - doctrine/orm=2.5
- **MariaDB**=10.2.14

### Solution :

**Commented** OR set value **'mariadb-10.2.14'** on the property `server_version` in your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`.

Highly inspired by : https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2985

Answer (score 0):

Try it -> `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete --dump-sql`

Or only

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete`

Comment: He says: The "--full-database" option does not exist.

Comment: He still shows the same on dump sql. Other updates worked but those for columns with keys doesn't.